# Java Process running from Windows Powershell sometimes randomly stops until pressing Ctr+C

Tags: java, powershell, freeze

I am running a Java process with several threads from a Powershell on Windows Server in Admin Mode.

Sometimes it randomly freezes until I press Ctrl+C, then it just picks up the work again.

Has anyone ever come across this problem and point me to where to look at?

Comment: I thought maybe this is a general known problem, since I expect the shell to kill the process by pressing Ctrl+C instead of recovering from a freeze. An explanation on how that behaviour is possible would be enough for me to get back and look for problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the process with Runtime.exec(..), it is sometimes necessary to read Bytes from the Process.getInputStream() resp. Process.getErrorStream(), else the process blocks, when it tries to write more to std-out (or std-err) than a certain buffer size.
I had this problem often, when starting Shell scripts.
You can create a Background Thread to read periodically from these streams.

Alternatively and more easy, you can use the ProcessBuilder class to start the shell process and use "inheritIO()" method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but doesn't starting the process with `java -jar process.jar` pipe all outputs to the console? So the streams should always be empty?

Comment: O, sorry. My answer is for the case, that you start a Shell from a Java process. but you did it the other way around. However, could be a similar issue, depending on how the Shell was started and where the Shells Output will go.